# Build dependencis for aws-sdk-go fails on Go version 1.13

Tags: go, aws-sdk-go

I have been trying to build a module on Go v1.13 with dependencies on `github.com/aws/aws-lambda-go` and `github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go` which fail on the two imports:

```
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws/service/s3"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws/service/s3/s3manager"
```

The stderr is as follows for `GOOS=linux GOARCH=amd64 go build -o dist/api ./api` where the `api` directory contains my module definition:

```
api/main.go:11:2: cannot find package "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws/service/s3" in any of:
        /usr/local/go/src/github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws/service/s3 (from $GOROOT)
        /u/go/src/github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws/service/s3 (from $GOPATH)
api/main.go:12:2: cannot find package "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws/service/s3/s3manager" in any of:
        /usr/local/go/src/github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws/service/s3/s3manager (from $GOROOT)
        /u/go/src/github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws/service/s3/s3manager (from $GOPATH)
```

Honestly, I have no clue why this is happening and any inputs would be appreciated.

Already tried using `go get` to ensure that the dependencies have been pulled:

```
$ go get github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go
```

and the requested import paths are present under `$GOPATH/src/github.com/aws/aws-sdk/go/aws/service/s3` and `$GOPATH/src/github.com/aws/aws-sdk/go/aws/service/s3/s3manager`

Also, tried clearing the cache using `go clean --cache --modcache` whilst removing previously pulled modules.

On closer inspection, something that I completely overlooked, the import path is `/u/go/src/github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws/service/s3` instead of `/u/go/src/github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/service/s3` with the former having an additional `aws` subpath inside `aws-sdk-go`.

Comment: Did you `go get` to download the dependencies?

Comment: Yes that was the first thing I tried. I see them pulled into `$GOPATH/src/github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/service/s3` but for some reason `build` cannot find them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just realized the copy/paste error I had made in the code.

```
import (
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws/service/s3"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws/service/s3/s3manager"
)
```

instead of

```
import (
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/service/s3"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/service/s3/s3manager"
)
```